# Avatar falls apart in SceneKit scene in iOS 17

Tags: scenekit, ios17

suddenly we found a problem in our app after iOS 17 release:
Everything works well on the SceneKit scene bellow iOS16. We can load an avatar and we can rotate nodes with given quaternions.
But in iOS 17 it falls apart as we want to make any rotation.
can anyone give me some hint what the problem can be?

in the attached image I show before and after rotation

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to post some code? like how the avatar is set up or how the rotation is made? (or can you share a reduced version of the project) ?

Comment: I load avatar:
let scene = SCNScene(named: "xxx.scn")!
sceneView.scene = scene
rotation: eg:
let hips = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "hips", recursively: true)!

hips.orientation = SCNQuaternion(0,0.7071068,0,0.7071068)

Comment: really hard to tell why this happens from iOS17 on. Without a project I cannot help you a lot here...

Comment: that is a good idea. I create a new project only with a sceneView and we see how it behaves

Answer (score 0):

solved
programmatically I added the root of the avatar to a node and that caused this issue... but still don't know why it has fallen apart...but at least it is solved

Comment: cool, congrats.